# Extending XHTML to Include Additional XML Schemas (XSD)

Tags: xml, xhtml, schema, extend

I'm teaching myself XML and XSDs and am piecing things together as I go along, so forgive me if this is a stupid question...

I've created a schema for a basic document, which I've imaginatively called basic document. All of the basic document elements are preceded by xs.

I would now like to extend XHTML by using the basic document I created - but I can't figure out how to create a new xml document that successfully pulls in the XHTML schema and the basic document schema that I've created.

Any guideance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are to allow (say) XHTML `<p>` elements as children, then your schema needs to do something like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xhtml="(the XHTML namespace)" ...
  <xs:import namespace="(the XHTML namespace)" schemaLocation="(location of the schema document for XHTML)">
  <xs:element name="my:element">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="xhtml:p"/>
    ....
```

Extending the XHTML schema to allow your elements is generally going to be more tricky, and it may not be possible: the XHTML schema might not be designed to allow that (I would need to check the details of the schema).